# How to add custom html block to list of footer options?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I am using the Debut theme on Shopify and wanting to customize my footer ([my site](https://sacredcoffeeco.com))

There are options within the customize theme to add and remove the column sections of the footer, however there is no option to add a custom html block as one of the columns. How can I add Custom HTML to this list of options for footer columns?:

[image: current footer options]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to update the `footer.liquid` and add a `block` to the existing code and then you able to see it into the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `/sections/footer.liquid` then add a new section block to the `blocks` array, this code should give you a basic starting point:

```json
{
  "type": "html_content",
  "name": "HTML Content",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "html",
      "id": "html_area",
      "label": "Custom HTML",
      "default": "<div><p>Some HTML content</p></div>"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then to display the content, you need to add a new type check for the `html_content` type in the `{%- case block.type -%}` block, like so:

```
{%- case block.type -%}
  {%- when 'newsletter' -%}
    .
    .
    .
  {%- when 'text' -%}
    .
    .
    .
  {%- when 'link_list' -%}
    .
    .
    .
  {%- when 'html_content' -%}
    {{ block.settings.html_area }}
{%- endcase -%}
```

When you save the change and refresh your theme customizer, you should be able to see a new content type in the footer section.

For all theme section input types [refer to this doc](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/settings#specialized-input-setting-types).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do I put in the 'Add your code here' ?

Comment: This `{{ block.settings.html_area }}` I updated the answer as well, if this answers your question correctly please mark it as the correct answer and if you upvoted it as well that would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you for your help!